# Is there a way, with styled components, to conditionally change the type of component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, styled-components

I have components that look identical with the same data, but sometimes I want it to be a link and sometimes a div, etc.
Can I have it be one component (because they have identical styles) and do something like pass in a prop to change the *type* of component?

For example:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const Container = styled.div`  *<<--- how do I make this styled.div OR styled(Link)*
    some styles here
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a prop in your component . Like `prop === true -> show as div` & if `prop === false -> show as link`. Then using ES6 you can achieve it as

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const Container = (prop) =  {

        { (prop===true) && return (JSX as a div) }

{(prop === false) && return (JSX for as a link) }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [forwardedAs prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#forwardedas-prop)

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <Container forwardedAs={"a"}>
    ...
  </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`as` prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop), its part of the official API:

> If you want to keep all the styling you've applied to a component but just switch out what's being ultimately rendered (be it a different HTML tag or a different custom component), you can use the "as" prop to do this at runtime.

```
const Div = styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <Div className="App" as="span">
      Hello
    </Div>
  );
}
```

Generates:

```
<span class="sc-hKgILt eQjPkS App">Hello</span>
```

[image: Edit As Prop]

Comment: Nice, thanks! Clean and straightforward